# What should I do with my Ubuntu phone now Ubuntu Touch is end-of-life?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I read that the support for Ubuntu phone OS ended on December 31, 2017.

I have an Aquaris E4.5 phone with Ubuntu phone OS. I would like to understand if I can use it with another operating system or if I'm destined to trash it. Thank you

Comment: You can flash it with Android 4.4 (https://itsfoss.com/install-android-ubuntu-phone/) or try UBPorts https://ubports.com/

Comment: You can install Android (version 4.4.2 or 5.0) following this: http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-articles/2015/09/16/ubuntu-android-installation-process-for-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-e5/

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu touch is not dead. Ubports support the system. Now it is in OTA 3 from Ubports and the activity is increasing wiht telegram channels...

Now dekko 2 (email client) has push, and telegram has all functionality. The next step is to support anbox that will allow you to install android applications in ubuntu phone and move to Ubuntu 16.04.

But you need flash it. Visit https://ubports.com/page/get-ubuntu-touch for more information:

INSTRUCTIONS: Install using system-image server

1. Install the required tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash phablet-tools
   ```
2. Reboot your device into fastboot mode and Connect your device with an USB cable to your computer.
3. Download adb unlocked recovery: http://cdimage.ubports.com/devices/recovery-krillin.img

   ```
   wget http://cdimage.ubports.com/devices/recovery-krillin.img
   ```
4. Flash your device using this command: (NOTE! This will wipe your phone!

   ```
    sudo ubuntu-device-flash --server=http://system-image.ubports.com touch --device=krillin \ --channel=ubports-touch/15.04/stable --bootstrap --recovery-image=recovery-krillin.img
   ```

Comment: @Rinzwind that's kind of a sad statement. So everything the community does doesn't matter, if it's not directly backed by Canonical? Then what are we even doing here? Isn't Askubuntu dead from a canonical point of view? Ubuntu is a community, and Ubuntu Touch is a lot more actively developed than officially supported versions like for example Edubuntu. Spreading that it's dead is a slap in the face to everyone who contributed to the project. Because *it is not*.

Comment: https://twitter.com/m_wimpress/status/1182701006490132480